Calculated column in MS Lists not ordering correctly?
I am trying to get a MS Lists calculated column to order numbers correctly (which subsequently is an issue in the PowerBI report that I pull using DirectQuery).
The column is to track Risk Weighting (combination of Likelihood and Impact), both of which are set to Number data type in the list, while my formula for the calculated column is as follows (again the data type to return is Number):

=IF(AND([Risk Impact]="1",[Risk Likelihood]="1"),"1",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="1",[Risk Likelihood]="2"),"3",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="1",[Risk Likelihood]="3"),"5",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="2",[Risk Likelihood]="1"),"6",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="1",[Risk Likelihood]="4"),"7",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="2",[Risk Likelihood]="2"),"8",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="2",[Risk Likelihood]="3"),"10",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="3",[Risk Likelihood]="1"),"11",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="2",[Risk Likelihood]="4"),"12",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="3",[Risk Likelihood]="2"),"13",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="3",[Risk Likelihood]="3"),"15",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="4",[Risk Likelihood]="1"),"16",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="3",[Risk Likelihood]="4"),"17",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="4",[Risk Likelihood]="2"),"18",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="4",[Risk Likelihood]="3"),"20",IF(AND([Risk Impact]="4",[Risk Likelihood]="4"),"22","0"))))))))))))))))

Currently this formula returns the results that I want, but when it comes to ordering the numbers (e.g. Larger to Smaller) they return as follows:



Current Sorting
Desired Sorting




8
17


8
17


8
17


7
17


6
15


17
15


17
15


17
10


17
10


15
8


15
8


15
8


10
7


10
6



If I remove the "speechmarks" from the formula, all rows calculate to 0.
Is my formula incorrect, or is this a constraint of SharePoint / Lists?

"my formula for the calculated column is as follows (again the data type to return is Number)" but what is the type of calculated field? If it is string it explains "incorrect" sorting.

@VladKarasovSharePointMCSE As per my response to Matiur Rahman, the calculated field is set to Number, as are the two fields I am using to calculate the value (although these themselves are calculated fields).

You may try a simple one first to see if the soring works as expected. My test with two number columns with a calculated number column (decimal place set to 0), sorting works as expected. No, you would not need to put number column values within double quote in your calculated formula. Maybe there is something wrong in the column values or in the formula.
=IF(MOD(NumberOne,2)=0,(NumberOne+NumberTwo),(NumberOne/NumberTwo))




Thanks for sharing this. In my example, I am actually using two calculated columns to calculate the final weighting i.e. in your example, NumberOne and NumberTwo are both calculated fields, which are then fed into the formula for CalculatedNumber.
All three calculated fields are set to 'Number' and 0 decimal place.
If I remove the double quote ("") from my formula, it no longer returns any values (i.e. everything resolves in 0).
